# how to make all cells readonly in TMSFMXGrid (in Firemonkey)?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle, tms

I am using Embarcadero® RAD Studio 10 Seattle Version 23.0.20618.2753

To make column read-only I used
`Grid_All_Party.Columns[2].ReadOnly := True;`

and

to make cell read-only I used

```
 Grid_All_Party.ReadOnlys[1,0] := True;
```

but how to make all cells of grid read-only without using the below code personally for all columns.

```
Grid_Name.Columns[column_number].ReadOnly := True;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Enabled` property controls whether editing is enabled.

From the [documentation](http://www.tmssoftware.biz/download/manuals/TMSFMXGridDevGuide.pdf):

Under `Editing`:

> Enabled: Boolean: Enables or disables editing in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

There is an options property which has lots of option for TMSFMXGrid. here is what you want:

```
Grid_Name.Options.Editing.Enabled:=false;
```